# Why Caffe refrense should go after sys in python?

Tags: python, deep-learning, caffe

I use Caffe framework and i use python language and have this code :

```
import numpy as np
import os
import matplotlib
import sys

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

caffe_root = '/home/jackson/caffe/'  # this file should be run from {caffe_root}/examples (otherwise change this line)
sys.path.insert(0, caffe_root + 'python')

import caffe

model_def = caffe_root + 'models/bvlc_reference_caffenet/deploy.prototxt'
model_weights = caffe_root + 'models/bvlc_reference_caffenet/bvlc_reference_caffenet.caffemodel'

net = caffe.Net(model_def,      # defines the structure of the model
                model_weights,  # contains the trained weights
                caffe.TEST)     # use test mode (e.g., don't perform dropout)
```

the problem is, when i move **import caffe** before **sys.path.insert(0, caffe_root + 'python')** i get this error :

> F0612 09:44:35.476567  5443 upgrade_proto.cpp:928] Check failed:
>   ReadProtoFromTextFile(param_file, param) Failed to parse NetParameter
>   file:
>   /home/jackson/caffe/models/bvlc_reference_caffenet/deploy.prototxt
>   *** Check failure stack trace: *** Aborted (core dumped)

Do Caffe and sys library have some sort of conflict ? Why did this happen? or it is because i change the module directory with **sys.path** ? (I should mention , without sys.path.insert the program would not run)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
caffe_root = '/home/jackson/caffe/'  # this file should be run from {caffe_root}/examples (otherwise change this line)
sys.path.insert(0, caffe_root + 'python')
```

This code put your /home/jackson/caffe/ folder at the beginning of your python import path,when you move it after i`mport caffe` ,python looks for caffe in other folders in your PYTHONPATH to see if caffe is installed,from what i see,you might have another caffe installed somewhere that is not compatible with the deploy.prototxt file you are using